# Blueprism - Limit Process Accessibility To Certain Resources

Tags: blueprism

I am trying to setup my processes so that certain bots/resources can and can't run them. I can see a capability drop down, but I don't know how to limit the capabilities.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am almost certain that the capability feature is not complete yet and it's something that will make its appearance in the following BP versions.

As far as I can think of, you could either take advantage of some of the Multi-team environment functions and hide some resources or processes for some groups of people, or you could use the `GetResourceName()` function to terminate your process if not executed on the white-listed machines.

Not ideal, we'll just have to see what the capabilities are about.

Comment: Thanks for this, I actually have to laugh that it's not available yet. I like your idea of get resource name. I might actually build one step further and query database to check it's got the correct configuration on our accounts. I would rather simply approve disapprove jobs though!